# hierarchical grid

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone help me how to create a hierarchical Ultrawebgrid in ASP.net using C#... I'm very new to this... So i need some basics and sample codes .. Can u help me ?

Comment: i know how to create a flat Ultrawebgrid but not the hierarchical one where we insert values for the child rows

Answer (score 3):

One way to make an UltraWebGrid "Hierarchical" is to establish a data relation in a dataset and bind the dataset to the UltraWebGrid.

As an example, let's say we have a Blog and we want to show the Blog Articles as the parent and then any comments made to each article as children in a Hierarchical UltraWebGrid.  The parent table is named "BlogArticle" and is keyed by "BlogArticleID" and the child table is named "BlogComment" and contains a "BlogArticleID" column as a foreign key to "BlogArticle".

First we would establish 2 datasets and fill them using whatever mechanism you prefer with the data we want.  In this case I am simply retrieving all the Blog Articles and all the Comments.  Then we would "merge" the dataset that is to be the child into the dataset that is to the parent.  Finally, we would set our data relationship in the dataset and bind the dataset to the UltraWebGrid.

An example of the code for this is as follows...

```
DataSet dsBlogArticle = new DataSet();
DataSet dsBlogComment = new DataSet();
//
// Fill each dataset appropriately.   
//
// Set Table Names.  This is needed for the merge operation.
dsBlogArticle.Tables[0].TableName = "BlogArticle";
dsBlogComment.Tables[0].TableName = "BlogComment";
//
// Merge the Blog Comment dataset into the Blog Article dataset
// to create a single dataset object with two tables.
dsBlogArticle.Merge(dsBlogComment);  
//
// Define Hierarchical relationships in the Dataset.
DataRelation dr = new DataRelation(
   "BlogArticleToComments",
   dsBlogArticle.Tables["BlogArticle"].Columns["BlogArticleID"],
   dsBlogArticle.Tables["BlogComment"].Columns["BlogArticleID"],
   false);
dsBlogArticle.Relations.Add(dr);    
//
// Bind the dataset to the grid.
this.grdBlogArticle.DataSource = dsBlogArticle;
this.grdBlogArticle.DataBind();
```

The UltraWebGrid will automatically handle creating the Hierarchical grid based on the Data Relationship that is established in the dataset.  To see this code populate an UltraWebGrid you can [go here](http://www.innovaapps.net/samples/) to view an example that I put together.

I hope this helps, Thanks

Comment: is there is any thing we need to add in html part of ultrawebgrid ?. I didn't get it using the same way. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/QuickGuideToImplementingTheNetAdvantageUltraWebGrid.aspx) what you are looking for?

Comment: hey thanks a lot for that link... it was very useful for me for an other purpose.... but i dint get wat i wanted "how to create a hierarchical Ultrawebgrid"Can u help me in this???

Comment: You may want to clarify exactly what you want: the article talks about representing records as a hierarchy, so I'm not sure I understand what you exactly mean by "hierarchical ultrawebgrid".
Do you have to use "ultrawebgrid"?